# Cons the first element of every sublist?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm writing a function to get me the children nodes of a parent, my code is:

```
(define (children elem tree)
  (if (eqv? tree '())
      '()
      (if (= elem (car tree))
          (getchilds (cdr tree))
          (children elem (cdr tree)))))

(define (getchilds childNodes)
  (cond ((null? childNodes) '())
        (else (cons (caar childNodes) (getchilds (cdr childNodes))))))
```

This half works.
`(children 10 '(10 (2 (4 (9 (3)) (12 (1 (2))) (16))) (5 (7) (21)) (6)))`
outputs `(2 5 6)` which is what I expect

but  `(children 2 '(10 (2 (4 (9 (3)) (12 (1 (2))) (16))) (5 (7) (21)) (6)))` fails.

I get a

```
=: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: (2 (4 (9 (3)) (12 (1 (2))) (16)))
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
```

I think it's because `(= elem (car tree)` expect a number as a second parameter, but if I do 
`(car '(2 (4 (9 (3)) (12 (1 (2))) (16))))`
output is `2`

So I'm not quite sure where my logic fails. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your input list of `(10 (2 (4 (9 (3)) (12 (1 (2))) (16))) (5 (7) (21)) (6))` (called `tree` in your code).

When you recurse with `(cdr tree)` (as you do in `(children elem (cdr tree))`), the new `tree` (in the recursive call) becomes `((2 (4 (9 (3)) (12 (1 (2))) (16))) (5 (7) (21)) (6))`. That means `(car tree)` is `(2 (4 (9 (3)) (12 (1 (2))) (16))) (5 (7) (21)) (6)`. That's not a number.

Comment: Thank you, of course I got stuck on something basic! I still had some logic errors, but it all works now. Thank you!

Comment: @cicero866 Dude, I'm there too.  Keep at it!  When you're new everything is just harder, but you'll get better